# AutoSuggest on Codeigniter (Ajax) - 404 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a functioning php application that uses the AutoSuggest JS script perfectly and now I'm porting the  same application to codeigniter. I'm not so good with CI that was the reason I wanted to try this out.
The problem it it's not working. below are the code.

JS part

```
  var options = {
        script:"/getPartnerLogo?",
        varname:"input",
        json:true,
        shownoresults:false,
        maxresults:6,
        callback: function (obj) { document.getElementById('partner1').value = obj.info;
        }
    };
    var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('pt1', options);
```

Code on the controller

```
function getPartnerLogo(){ 

    $aUsers = array(
      "HSBC",
      "Spinneys"
    );


    $aInfo = array(
      "HSB",
      "SPN"
    );

    $input = trim($this->input->get('input'));
    $len = strlen($input);
    $limit = 6;
    $aResults = array();
    $count = 0;

    if ($len)
    {
        for ($i=0;$i<count($aUsers);$i++)
        {

            if (strtolower(substr(utf8_decode($aUsers[$i]),0,$len)) == $input)
            {
                $count++;
                $aResults[] = array( "id"=>($i+1) ,"value"=>htmlspecialchars($aUsers[$i]), "info"=>htmlspecialchars($aInfo[$i]) );
            }

            if ($limit && $count==$limit)
                break;
        }
    }

    header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
    header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); // always modified
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header ("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0

        header("Content-Type: application/json");

        echo "{\"results\": [";
        $arr = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<count($aResults);$i++)
        {
            $arr[] = "{\"id\": \"".$aResults[$i]['id']."\", \"value\": \"".$aResults[$i]['value']."\", \"info\": \"".$aResults[$i]['info']."\"}";
        }
        echo implode(", ", $arr);
        echo "]}";
    }

    }
```

Now when I access the controller direct it returns the json properly.

```
http://localhost/cd/getPartnerLogo?input=h
```

{"results": [{"id": "3", "value": "HSBC", "info": "HSB"}]}

But when I try is from the JS it gives me a 404 error. When I track the network calls form inspect elements the response is the default 404 error page from CI.

Can anyone please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your request URL.
most of the time when you are working on **localhost**, ajax request failed because of some mistakes in URL.

for example your script is under `localhost/dc` but your ajax request send to `localhost/`.
you can config virtual host and setup domain on your localhost or setting base url on all ajax requests at must be absolute url.
to check where your requests goes to, you can check them in your firefox/chrome network tab under development tools.